# Filter Returns Blank Report Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I have an index page in an Access 2010 report that gives a list of projects based on a bunch of search criteria. There's about 20 fields that the user can specify.

For example, if the user searches for projects in area A that start in 2015, it should bring up projects that meet both specifications. If they search for a specific project number, it should list only that one. If they leave it blank, all projects should come up.

Whenever I try and run the report, the pages relating to the projects are fine but the Index - which is basically a table of contents with some additional information (start year, area, ...) - is blank. I'm trying to use SQL to display a list of the projects included in the report.

```
    SELECT * FROM [INDEX] AS i 
WHERE
        i.area = Forms![SearchForm]![txtArea]
    AND i.year = Forms![SearchForm]![txtStartYear]
    AND i.ProjNo = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]
;
```

I'm working with a few fields to start to get at least that much working. I'm not good with SQL, and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail to my question. I don't know if that helps, but the data itself is fairly involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one text box, eg *Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]*, you want ...

1. when the text box has a non-Null value, only rows whose *ProjNo* values match that text box value
2. when the text box is Null, the query results should not be filtered on *ProjNo* --- in other words a row could be included regardless of its *ProjNo* value

That requirement is actually fairly easy to translate into SQL:

```sql
WHERE
    (
           i.ProjNo = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]
        OR Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo] Is Null
    )
```

Compare that SQL to the plain language explanation above.

Assuming that first piece is clear, add in the conditions for a second text box.

```sql
WHERE
    (
           i.ProjNo = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo]
        OR Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjNo] Is Null
    )
    AND
    (
           i.area = Forms![SearchForm]![txtArea]
        OR Forms![SearchForm]![txtArea] Is Null
    )
```

From there, add in additional `AND (field_name = text_box OR text_box Is Null)` pieces for each of your remaining field/text box pairs.

Note I presumed the text box values are Null if the user doesn't enter a search value.  However, if they are actually empty strings (`''`) instead of Null,
substitute `OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtArea]) = 0` in place of `OR Forms![SearchForm]![txtArea] Is Null`

Or if a "blank" text box could be either Null or `''`, use this: `OR Len(Forms![SearchForm]![txtArea] & '') = 0`

Comment: This gives me the same problem as my original code; It only works if there's only one filter. As soon as I add the `AND`, it gives me a blank report.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your database?

Comment: It's not a personal database, so I'm not at liberty to share it. I made the correction using `Len(Forms...)` and it works if I search only by the last criteria in the code.

Comment: On second thought, it looks like it might just be the Area field messing it up. I tried with a different field and it looks like it's working with those.